# How to do a SQL-type INNER JOIN in Python and only naming a couple of column names?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, join

I am experienced with SQL, but am new to Python.

I am attempting to use the join or pandas.merge functions to complete the following simple SQL Join:

```
SELECT
a.Patient_ID,
a.Physician,
b.Hospital
FROM DF1 a
INNER JOIN DF2 b
on a.Patient_ID=b.Patient_ID_Number
```

Here is as close as I've gotten:

```
import pandas as pd
output=pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how='inner', left_on='Patient_ID', right_on='Patient_ID_Number')
```

However, this produces the equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM DF1 a
    INNER JOIN DF2 b
    on a.Patient_ID=b.Patient_ID_Number
```

I'm not familiar with indexing or keys, so I am trying to implement a simple code translation only for now. If it's not integral but just a nice feature, I will learn it later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the columns in the join statement:

```
 output=pd.merge(DF1[['Patient_ID','Physician']], DF2[['Hospital','Patient_ID_Number']], how='inner', left_on='Patient_ID', right_on='Patient_ID_Number')
```

You do have to carry over both columns that you're joining on in your statement

You can specify which columns to keep before your join statement

```
DF1=DF1[['Patient_ID','Physician']]
DF2=DF2[['Patient_ID_Number','Hospital']]
output=pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how='inner', left_on='Patient_ID', right_on='Patient_ID_Number')
```

Or only keep the columns after your join statement

```
output=output[['Patient_ID','Physician','Hospital']]
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!